Consume csv in a streaming fashion then produce chunked response using spring webflux
Using webflux i would like to process a csv file in a streaming fashion and produce a chunked ndjson streamed response where each chunk is the result of the processing of each consumed line.
So using the PartEvent example from the documentation the following endpoint can be defined:
    @PostMapping(path = "/process",
            consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_NDJSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public Flux<Data> process(@RequestBody Flux<PartEvent> allPartsEvents) {
        return allPartsEvents.windowUntil(PartEvent::isLast)
            .concatMap(p -> p.switchOnFirst((signal, partEvents) -> {
                if (signal.hasValue()) {
                    PartEvent event = signal.get();
                    if (event instanceof FormPartEvent formEvent) {
                        String value = formEvent.value();
                        System.out.println("FormPartEvent: " + value);
                        return Flux.just(new Data(value));
                    }
                    else if (event instanceof FilePartEvent fileEvent) {
                        String filename = fileEvent.filename();
                        System.out.println("Processing file: " + filename);
                        Flux<Data> contents =
                                partEvents.map(PartEvent::content)
                                .map( dataBuffer -> {
                                    byte[] bytes = new byte[dataBuffer.readableByteCount()];
                                    dataBuffer.read(bytes);
                                    String line = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                                    System.out.println("line -> " + line);
                                    DataBufferUtils.release(dataBuffer);

                                    return new Data(line);
                                });
                        return contents;
                    }
                    else {
                        return Flux.error(new RuntimeException("Unexpected event: " + event));
                    }
                }
                else {
                    return Flux.error(new RuntimeException("Unexpected"));
                }
            }));
    }

The problem is that file is read completely into memory but i would like to process it line by line.
I was expecting to find something in DataBufferUtils class to read a DataBuffer line by line then feed it to a csv parser but there is nothing.
Is there a reactive way to consume csv data using spring webflux?
